# In a Pandas dataframe how do I select all rows that match a given Year and Month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example data:

```
       U_ID     Group  Location      Hours        Date
79     149        17      USA           2       2014-11-03
80     149        17      USA           2       2014-11-07
81     149        21      USA           3       2014-12-21
82     149        18      UK           1.5      2014-11-14
83     149        19      Spain         2       2014-11-21
```

I am looking to sum the hours that fall into the same month when the group and Location are the same so:

```
79     149        17      USA           2       2014-11-03
80     149        17      USA           2       2014-11-07
```

would become the following in a new dataframe:

```
1      149        17      USA          4       2014-11-01
```

I can work out most of this except the most efficient way to select data that matches a given year and month so in this example how would I select everything in November 2014?

I was planning to iterate over the frame row by row and then track which rows have been processed (so I don't create duplicates):

def process_ids(s_df):
    processed_ids = pd.DataFrame(columns=['U_ID'], dtype='str')

```
for i, row in s_df.iterrows():
    if processed_ids['U_ID'].str.contains(row['U_ID']).any():
        continue
    else:
        processed_ids = processed_ids.append({"U_ID": str(row['U_ID'])}, ignore_index=True)
```

I now just need to filter by year and month and then check they have the same Group and Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregation sum with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) for grouping by start of months `MS`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location',pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])['Hours']
         .sum()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   U_ID  Group Location       Date  Hours
0   149     17      USA 2014-11-01    4.0
1   149     18       UK 2014-11-01    1.5
2   149     19    Spain 2014-11-01    2.0
3   149     21      USA 2014-12-01    3.0
```

And then select by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df1[df1['Date'] == '2014-11-01'])
   U_ID  Group Location       Date  Hours
0   149     17      USA 2014-11-01    4.0
1   149     18       UK 2014-11-01    1.5
2   149     19    Spain 2014-11-01    2.0

print (df1[df1['Date'] == '2014-12-01'])
   U_ID  Group Location       Date  Hours
3   149     21      USA 2014-12-01    3.0
```

---

If want select by `datetime`s is possible a bit change solution for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location',pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])['Hours']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(level=[0,1,2]))
print (df1)
            U_ID  Group Location  Hours
Date                                   
2014-11-01   149     17      USA    4.0
2014-11-01   149     18       UK    1.5
2014-11-01   149     19    Spain    2.0
2014-12-01   149     21      USA    3.0
```

And select by [`partial string indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing):

```
print (df1['2014-11'])
            U_ID  Group Location  Hours
Date                                   
2014-11-01   149     17      USA    4.0
2014-11-01   149     18       UK    1.5
2014-11-01   149     19    Spain    2.0

print (df1['2014-12'])
            U_ID  Group Location  Hours
Date                                   
2014-12-01   149     21      USA    3.0
```

EDIT:

If want also keep original `Date`s for not aggregate groups one possible solution is add dictionary for aggregation for count groups by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), last replace values by condition with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) only one row groups, with length 1:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])
             .agg({'Hours':'sum', 'U_ID':'size','Date':'first'})
             .rename(columns={'Date':'processed date','U_ID':'len group'})
             .reset_index()
             )

df1['processed date'] = np.where(df1['len group'].eq(1), df1['processed date'], df1['Date'])

print (df1)
   U_ID  Group Location       Date  Hours  len group processed date
0   149     17      USA 2014-11-01    4.0          2     2014-11-01
1   149     18       UK 2014-11-01    1.5          1     2014-11-14
2   149     19    Spain 2014-11-01    2.0          1     2014-11-21
3   149     21      USA 2014-12-01    3.0          1     2014-12-21
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael - I can see how this works, how would I keep the original date series in df1 as well? and label the resulting Grouper series say 'processed date'?

Comment: Not sure if understand, e.g. from `2014-11-03 and 2014-11-07` is created `2014-11-01`. What do you think output from `2014-11-03 and 2014-11-07` ?

Comment: Say for Location: Spain. this had a date of  2014-11-21 it's not rolled up or summed but the date is replaced with 2014-11-01. In this instance can 2014-11-21 remain? Maybe I just copy the Date series in the original frame to keep a copy, say source_date?

Comment: @user7186882 - added solution for `date` for one elemet groups. If want aggregate first value per groups, only remove `np.where` line.